I left a question in the chat
I'm not fully aware regarding what type of questions are well-received in this site, and I could not provide a reliable source for my question (instead, I was looking for it).
So I added a question to the chat, if someone could help me there.
Thanks :D.
[EDIT for further cases like this:
I finally posted my question, which is this one, and my doubts regarding this question's fitness in the site were these:

I read the claim long time ago. Quite long time ago.
I cannot remember most of the details, except those stated in the question.
I cannot find a reference to a reliable source. In face: I was asking if such reliable source existed.

And since this is one of my first questions on the site and am not sure how this site operates]

Can you add the question here too?

In general, the best option is probably to do your best and just ask the question on the main site. If you put in a bit of effort, you'll find that most established users will be keen to engage and help you in framing the question.
Equally, if it's really not appropriate for the site, you'll get feedback.
If a question does get closed and you want additional clarification, then you can always ask more general questions about what's on topic on meta.
